# Get the UTC offset in Python

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

I am trying to get the UTC offset for the local time in seconds as an `int`. I can do this in a roundabout way:

```py
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
timezone = now.astimezone().tzinfo
offset = timezone.utcoffset(now).seconds
```

There must be a better way, but I haven't been able to find it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

`time.timezone` gives the offset of the local non-DST timezone.

When a DST timezone is active, `time.daylight` is non-zero, and `time.altzone` gives you the UTC offset of the local DST timezone.

To account for all cases, you'd need to check `time.daylight` and select the offset accordingly:

```
import time

offset = time.altzone if time.daylight else time.timezone
```

The [docs for the `time` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#timezone-constants) contain more information.

Answer (score 1):

I found that I can shorten the formula somewhat, so it can be a single statement:

```py
from datetime import datetime

offset = datetime.now().astimezone().utcoffset().seconds
```

Comment: Note that this is equally roundabout as your original snippet.

Comment: The reason I feel this is somewhat better is that the first attempt had to make a variable for the local time, then input that variable into a method of one of its own attributes; while the new approach has only a single strait string of calls. I'm still looking for a better way.

Comment: Okay, I misread this snippet, it's 1 attribute less roundabout than the original. If you set `timezone = now.astimezone()` in your original code, you could do `timezone.utcoffset().seconds` without passing `now` to the function. I added an answer that uses attributes of the `time` module to get the same information, but it still involves checking if DST is active.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
print(time.timezone - time.daylight*3600)
```

That prints 25200, because I am currently 7 hours behind GMT, and 8 hours is 25200 seconds.

(I'm in PDT.)

Comment: This gets messed up with daylight savings time, doesn't it?

Comment: Correct.  Let me patch it.

Comment: Shouldn't that be *3600 (seconds)?

Comment: Between us all, we'll get it right.  This is why people hate dealing with time zones.